# Angular 2 show login | logout link

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to show login | logout link on the base of logged in user.
I'm saving 'currentUser' object in auth.service:
`localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));`

When I tried to , `console.log('navbar.component',this.currentUser);` in navbar.component.ts, it shows `null`, but when console it in home.component, it display me user, home.component is protected using auth guard, please have a look at my code and suggest some good solution.

Angular Version: `4.0.2`

directory Structure:

```
quickstart
 -src
   --app
       --_guards
       _services
       --navbar
           navbar.component.ts
       --home
         home.component.ts
      --login
         login.component
   app.component.ts
   app.component.html 
   app-routing.module.ts
```

navbar.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit{
    private projectName;
    private currentUser: any;
    constructor(){this.projectName = 'Web Shop Admin';}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log('navbar.component',this.currentUser);
        // null in console
    }
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="currentUser !== null " class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Welcome {{currentUser.name}}</a></li>

     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">(Logout)</a></li>
  </ul>
```

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    currentUser: any;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log('home.component',this.currentUser);
       //display me the current user
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  { 
    private currentUser: any;
    constructor(){
         this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        //display me the current user
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<navbar></navbar>

<alert></alert>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<footer class="container-fluid">
    <p class="text-center small">©2016-2017 Company</p>
</footer>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
...
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {path:'category', component:CategoryComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path:'product', component:ProductComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    {path:'**', redirectTo:''}
]
....
```

Comment: when you open the page for the first time the user is null and the loggin in happens after wards , the value of user is fetched in navbar at ngOninit , so the value remains null. so after logging in you have to fire an emiiter to tell the navbar component to update

Comment: can you please post an answer with example emitter?

Comment: can you add a pluker for the same ?

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce?